# Sharepoint Modern (communication) page: how to add multiple libraries

Tags: web-part, modern-pages, communication-site

I would like to add 2 different libraries to one **modern** (communication) page.
Is that possible?

In the classic pages you can create your own web parts and add them to pages. So in that case I can create 2 library **web parts**, customize them and add these to the page. But is seems that that is not possible in modern pages.

I hope I am wrong and it *is* possible. 
Any suggestions how to solve this from an end-user perspective? Is it anyhow possible to add web-parts to the page, other than the default ones Microsoft provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple document libraries to your site by visiting the Site Contents page and choosing New then selecting library.

You can surface these libraries using the out of the box Documents web part and selecting the appropriate library.

You can also create your own modern webparts using the [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).